# Why don't c compiler throws error if I try storing values greater than what I specified during dynamic allocation?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is what I have tried. I have not even ended my string with a `\0` character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int size=5;
    char *str = (char *)malloc((size)*sizeof(char));
    *(str+0) = 'a';
    *(str+1) = 'b';
    *(str+2) = 'c';
    *(str+3) = 'd';
    *(str+4) = 'e';
    *(str+5) = 'f';
    printf("%d    %s", (int)strlen(str), str);
    return 0;
}
```

According to the rule, it can store only 4 charaters and one for the `\0` as I have specified it in malloc.
It gives me the perfect output.

**Output**

```
6    abcdef
```

Check this out here : https://onlinegdb.com/B1UeOXbjH

Comment: FYI: `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1, so you can just do `malloc(size)`. `siezof` returns the size of the type in multiples of the size of `char`, and since `char` is exactly 1 `char` long, `sizeof(char)` is always 1, regardless of platform.

Comment: Also, `strlen` returns a `size_t`, which you can print in `printf` with the `%zu` specifier. This avoids the cast and works portably (e.g. on 64bit platforms where `size_t` is 64bit but `int` may be 32bit).

Comment: Because the C standard does not require it.   Falling off the end of a dynamically allocated array gives undefined behaviour, according to the standard.     When behaviour is undefined,  no diagnostic (in your words  "throw error") is required.    The reason the standard does this is that it is not always technically possible for a compiler to detect undefined behaviour.   Your case is simple.   More complicated cases, which give the same effect, can be technically very difficult - or even impossible - to detect before the program is run - which is after the compiler has finished its job.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You allocated your own memory, so it is up to you to manage it responsibly.  In your example, you allocated 5 bytes of RAM, and you created a pointer which points to the first address of it.  Your pointer is not a string, it is not an array.  So, what you then did was you wrote 6 bytes, starting at the address pointed to by your pointer.  The 6th byte is overflowing into unallocated memory.  So you wrote it into memory which may be used for something else and could cause unknown problems. You have created a leak, and you didn't free up the memory you allocated when you quit the program, which is another leak.  You didn't add in a /0 anywhere so I honestly think you lucked out.  There really isn't any way to know how strlen() would respond.  If you want C to handle it for you, than you have `char *str = "abcdef"` and that will create your string of length 6 plus the /0.  But if you do it manually like you did, than you have to handle everything.

Answer (score -1):

C does not count its arrays: if you ask for a chunk of memory of so-many bytes, it gives you that chunk via a pointer, and it's entirely up to you to manage it responsibly.

This leads to a certain efficiency - no overhead from the compiler/runtime checking all this for you - but creates enormous challenges for incorrect code (which you've shown an example of).

Many of us every much like the down-to-the-metal efficiency of C, but there's a reason that so many prefer languages such as Java or C# that do manage this for you, and enforce array bounds.  It's a tradeoff.